# List of select data in Entity Framework (linq)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

This is my function:

```
 Public Function GetAllEmployee() As List(Of Employees)
    Return DB.Employees.Select(Function(q) New With {q.EmployeeID, q.LastName,q.FirstName}).ToList()
End Function
```

I'm getting an error:

> Value of type `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of <anonymous type>)` cannot be converted to `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of NorthwindModel.Employees)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're instantiating an [Anonymous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) object inside your select statement. Try using this:

```
Return DB.Employees.ToList()
```

**EDIT**: If you want to give back a list of objects with only those 3 properties, you can define a class containing those properties:

```
Public Class MyEmployees
    Public Property EmployeeId As Long
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
End Class
```

Then return a list of that new class:

```
Public Function GetAllEmployee() As List(Of MyEmployees)
    Return DB.Employees.Select(Function(q) New MyEmployees With { .EmployeeId = q.EmployeeID, .LastName = q.LastName, .FirstName = q.FirstName}).ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: You can remove the `Select` altogether in this case.

Comment: but i want only three field(employeeid,fname,lname).